# MVC Html.ActionLink doesn't work after upgrade from .net 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Well as the title says, I have a project with a bunch of Html.ActionLink

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Reason for booking", "BookingReason")%>
```

I have upgraded the project to .net 4.0 and they no longer render a link to the action.  Its just a blank  of course causing the page to reload.

The Html.ActionLink tags are in a user control (ascx) in the Shared folder of an Area.

I tried downgrading again to .net 3.5 and it works - weird.  any ideas?

Thx

Comment: What HTML is being rendered by the `ActionLink` when you upgrade to .NET 4.0 and how does it differ from the generated HTML under .NET 3.5?

Comment: Yes - im .net 3.5 I get the link with the href to the action with, in .net 4 I get <a href=''> nothing...sends me to the route of the site.

Comment: Also tried Url.Action and the same.
I meant root of the Controller so http://site/controller/

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to mark your optional params with `UrlParameter.Optional`

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

That was the problem for us (symptoms as yours).

-- Edited
It wasn't the only problem.
When migrating to MVC 3 you can get next problem,
suppose you had such route(`id` and `page` were optional)

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", page = "" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

now you have to split it to 2 different routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Paged",                                                     // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{page}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                                     // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}//, page = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it.

I needed to have a default route above my custom ones...must have removed it at some point.

Still weird how it works in .net 3.5 and not 4.

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Name",
            "AreaName/{action}",
            new { controller = "defaultController", action = "defaultAction" }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was the answer for me.. :)

Well the solution to work `<%= Html.ActionLink("Reason for booking", "BookingReason")%>` is

- In 3.5 it works with `<%= Html.ActionLink("Reason for booking", "BookingReason")%>`
- In 4.0 it works with `<%: Html.ActionLink("Reason for booking", "BookingReason")%>`

**Difference : 3.5 - "=" and 4.0 - ":"**

Hope that solves your problem too..